# How can I caculate the density function of $\frac{(1-a^2)^2}{1-2a^2\cos(2 \beta \pi R)+a^4}$ with $R \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, computational-mathematics

I have a gaussian distributed variable $R$ with a mean of $\mu$ and standard deviation of $\sigma$,the variance is the square of the standard deviation. The formula for the measurement uses $\frac{(1-a^2)^2}{1-2a^2\cos(2\beta \pi R)+a^4}$ in the calculation, where $R \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and the other parameters are constant in the formula. I need to know the density function that result from taking the formula $\frac{(1-a^2)^2}{1-2a^2\cos(2\beta \pi R)+a^4}$. How can I calculate that?

Comment: The expression can be simplified by introducing arbitrary constants. In particular, your expression is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{c_1 + c_2 \cos(c_3 Z + c_4)}$$ where the $c_i$ are chosen appropriately and $Z$ is standard normal.

Comment: how can I calculate this new expression? Thank you!

Comment: $c_3 Z + c_4$ is itself a normal random variable. It looks like [obtaining an expression for the distribution of the cosine of a normal random variable is nontrivial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35260/resultant-probability-distribution-when-taking-the-cosine-of-gaussian-distribute). But a better question to ask yourself is...why do you need an expression? Can you just sample from it a bunch of times and use the [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) for whatever you are doing?